# How to not Allow Some Matrices Together

Tags: github, github-actions

I've configured my matrices in my workflow file as below:

```
matrix:
  python-version: [3.5, 3.6, 3.7]
  django-version: [1.11, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2]
```

Some of these naturally fail on testing, specifically Python 3.7 and Django 1.11, giving the output below (if relevant):

```
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.5/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.filters import (
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.5/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/filters.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.options import IncorrectLookupParameters
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.5/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin import helpers, widgets
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.5/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py", line 151
    '%s=%s' % (k, v) for k, v in params.items(),
```

So, I somehow need to tell Github Actions that "Cancel if Python is 3.7 *and* Django is 1.11.". I've looked into documentations and stuff but could not figure it out. I've tried something like below in my steps:

```
if: (matrix.python-version != 3.7 && matrix.django-version != 1.11)
# or
if: (matrix.python-version != 3.7) && (matrix.django-version != 1.11)
```

However, this cancels *all* Django 1.11 and *all* Python 3.7.

Is there a way to ban some matrix combinations in Github Actions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if: !(matrix.python-version == 3.7 && matrix.django-version == 1.11)
```

Or

```
if: (matrix.python-version != 3.7 || matrix.django-version != 1.11)
```

An alternative is to use the [exclude](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-excluding-configurations-from-a-matrix) option for matrix builds

So something like:

```
matrix:
  exclude:
    - python-version: 3.7
      django-version: 1.11
```

Comment: the `exclude` option is the best: it avoids having to write the if condition at each step.